How can I make a channel I'm following send updates to a thread of a channel instead of a channel?
I followed a channel in another server to get updates about what's going on in Helldivers 2, but I want it to send updates to a thread I've created instead of a text channel (which is what it does currently).
If I go to Server Settings > Apps > Integrations > Channels Followed, I get this Post To dropdown

but the thread I created doesn't show up.
Is it possible to make updates send to a thread instead of a channel?

Simple answer: no, this is not possible.
The reason is because Discord intends for threads to be a scoped, temporary conversation. Threads are seen as extensions to text channels, so Discord accepts text channels and not threads. Some workarounds include making a custom bot.
